# questions about the testing of the xloper xll

Tags: c++, c, add-in, xll

code as follows:

```
'''
int __stdcall xloper_type(const xloper *type){
   if(type->xltype&~(xlbitXLFree|xlbitDLLFree)==xltypeRef)
        return xltypeRef;
}
'''
```

why to use ~(xlbitXLFree|xlbitDLLFree) when testing pointer type's xltype?? thanks!

Comment: How is 'xloper' defined? As XLOPER or XLOPER12? Presumably there is some other code in the function which checks for other types?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the relevant section from xlcall.h which defines the XLOPER data type. I don't know how 'xloper' (lower case) is defined in the OP's code (whether XLOPER or XLOPER12), but for XLOPER the xltype member is an unsigned int (WORD). Each bit corresponds to a different flag, so you can use bit-wise operations.

The xlbitXLFree and xlbitDLLFree are bits that indicate who (Excel or you) is responsible for cleaning up any memory allocated to the OPER (eg if it contains a string, or array). So typically, if you allocate any memory for the OPER in your xll, the xlbitDLLFree bit will be set to 1, and Excel will expect you to tidy up afterwards (passing the OPER to the xlAutoFree() function that should be declared somewhere in your xll code).

So

```
type->xltype&~(xlbitXLFree|xlbitDLLFree)
```

zeroes out the memory allocation bits in a bit-wise AND NOT() operation, leaving you with just the basic type. Eg if you received a string from Excel into your code, it's xltype would likely be xltypeStr & xlbitXLFree (Excel will tidy up), so 0x1002, which would not be equal to xltypeStr (0x0002), hence the need the bit-wise operation before you check for the OPER underlying type.

A neater way to write this might be (depending on requirements)

```
if(type->xltype & xltypeRef) {}
```

as the result will be non-zero (true) if the bit matching xltypeRef (0x0008) is set in type->xltype.

```
/*
** XLOPER and XLOPER12 data types
**
** Used for xltype field of XLOPER and XLOPER12 structures
*/

#define xltypeNum        0x0001
#define xltypeStr        0x0002
#define xltypeBool       0x0004
#define xltypeRef        0x0008
#define xltypeErr        0x0010
#define xltypeFlow       0x0020
#define xltypeMulti      0x0040
#define xltypeMissing    0x0080
#define xltypeNil        0x0100
#define xltypeSRef       0x0400
#define xltypeInt        0x0800

#define xlbitXLFree      0x1000
#define xlbitDLLFree     0x4000
```

Comment: many days not to login on website ,thank you for your answer ,i catch it!